# What does it mean for a variable to be free for something?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

"If $\mathscr{B}$ is a wf and $t$ is a term, then $t$ is said to be *free* for $x_i$ in $\mathscr{B}$ if no free occurrence of $x_i$ in $\mathscr{B}$  lies within the scope of any quantifier $(\forall x_j)$, where $x_j$ is a variable in $t$."

This is how Mendelson defines the expression 'free for $x_i$ in $\mathscr{B}$'. He goes on to say that it means that, if $t$ is substituted for all free occurrences (if any) of
$x_i$ in $\mathscr{B}(x_i)$, no occurrence of a variable in $t$ becomes a bound occurrence in $\mathscr{B}(t)$'.

I still can't understand what '**free for**' means. Could anyone provide examples along with explanations?

Mendelson also distinguishes between 'free for', 'free' and 'free occurrence', distinctions that I haven't yet fully grasped.

Comment: For example, you can't substitute a variable y for x if y occurs in the scope of a quantifier where x is bound. y would be free but not free for x.

Comment: To be free means to be able to drink beer. Ah wait this is stack.SE and not philosophy, oops.

Answer (score 6):

We have formulas $\phi(x)$ with *free* occurrences of $x$, like e.g. $x=0$.

If we put a quantifier in front, what we get is $\forall x \phi(x)$. The formula $\phi(x)$ will be the *scope* of the leading quantifier and all occurrences of $x$ in $\phi(x)$ will be *bound*, because they are in the scope of the quantifier.

We can formalize it through an "operator" $\text {FV}$ that takes in input a formula $\phi$ and gives as output the set of free variables of the formula (see [van Dalen](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA62), page 62):

> if $\phi$ is an *atomic* formula, like e.g. $x=0$, all variables in $\phi$ are *free* (in our example, $\text {FV}(x=0)= \{ x \}$).

Things are smooth for formulas with propositional connectives; the only interesting cases are those with quantifiers:

> $\text {FV}(∃yψ)=\text {FV}(∀yψ)=\text {FV}(ψ) \setminus \{ y \}$.

---

The locution “$t$ is *free for* $x$ in $ϕ$” (where $t$ is a *term*, $x$ a *variable* and $\phi$ a *formula*) comes down to the fact that the (obviously free) variables of $t$ are not going to be bound after substitution in $ϕ$.

Thus, to be "free for" must ensure that a proper substitution is performed, producing a "correct" result $ϕ[t/x]$.

In order to do this, we need a formal defintion:

> $t$ is *free for* $x$ in $ϕ$ if
>
> > (i) $ϕ$ is atomic;
> >
> > (ii) $ϕ$ is $ϕ_1 \lor ϕ_2$ (or is $ϕ_1 \land ϕ_2$, or is $¬ϕ_1$) and $t$ is free for $x$ in $ϕ_1$ and $ϕ_2$;
> >
> > (iii) $ϕ$ is $∃yψ$ (or $∀yψ$) and if $x ∈ \text{FV}(ϕ)$, then $y \notin \text{FV}(t)$ and $t$ is free for $x$ in $ψ$.

---

Consider now the simple example of a formula $\phi$:

> $\exists y (y+x = 0)$,

and consider as $t$ the term: $y+1$.

The substitution $\phi[t/x]$ will produce:

> $\exists y (y+y+1 = 0)$,

that is clearly wrong: $0$ is not the *successor* of any number.

What has gone wrong ? The fact that $t$ is **not** free for $x$ in $\phi$.

Why so ? Because we have violated the part (iii) of the above definition: $x \in \text {FV}(\phi)$ but $y \in \text {FV}(t)$, and thus the free occurrence of $y$ in $t$ has been "captured" by the leading quantifier.

Consider now this example in light of Mendelson's definition:

> "If $\mathscr{B}$ is a wf and $t$ is a term, then $t$ is said to be *free* for $x_i$ in $\mathscr{B}$ if no free occurrence of $x_i$ in $\mathscr{B}$  lies within the scope of any quantifier $(\forall x_j)$ [or $(\exists x_j)$], where $x_j$ is a variable in $t$."

And rewrite our formula as: $\exists x_j (x_j + x_i = 0)$; now the term $t$ is $x_j+1$.

We want to replace $x_i$ with $t$ into $\mathscr{B}$: unfortunately we cannot do it, because $t$ is not *free for* $x_i$.

In fact we have that the only free occurrence of $x_i$ in $\mathscr{B}$ lies within the scope of a quantifier $\exists x_j$, where $x_j$ is a variable in $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I came across a similarly cryptic definition of "free for" in Kohei Kishida's Phd thesis "Generalised Topological Semantics for First Order Modal Logic" published 2010, p57.