# Can free variable substitution change the meaning of the formula?

Tags: logic, set-theory, predicate-logic

I am reading https://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf. Page 14 asserts the following algorithm is executed on a formula $\Phi$ when substituting a variable $v_j$ for each free occurrence of a variable $v_i$ in $\Phi$:

1. Substitute a new variable $v_l$ for all bound occurrences of a $v_i$ in $\Phi$
2. Substitute a new variable $v_k$ for all bound occurrences of a $v_j$ in the result of (1)
3. Directly substitute $v_j$ for each occurrence of $v_i$ in the result of (2)

Now suppose $\Phi$ is $(¬(v_i = v_j))$ and we would like to substitute $v_j$ for all free occurrences of $v_i$. Steps (1) and (2) does nothing because neither $v_i$ nor $v_j$ are bound in $\Phi$. (3) produces $(¬(v_j = v_j))$, which changes $\Phi$'s meaning. Is this supposed to happen or did I make a mistake? The new formula doesn't make sense logically.

Comment: Your example is fine... in principle. For semantics, usually, free variable are implicitly universally quantified: thus $\lnot (x = y)$ "means" $\forall x \forall y \lnot (x=y)$ that already includes the "wrong" $\lnot (x=x)$.

Comment: BUT the author at this stage is defining only the syntactical operation of *substitution* and it is what it is. See Following comment regarding "capturing" of free var by quantifiers. Thus, we have to define the further operation of "correct substitution" that is usually defined through the concept of "freely substitutable" of "free for".

Comment: See e.g. [How does substitution work in predicate logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415045/how-does-substitution-work-in-predicate-logic)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you!