# variable-free terms and substitutability

Tags: logic, model-theory, substitution

I'm reading "A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic - Christopher C. Leary" and there is an exercise (in page 36) saying "Show that if $t$ is variable-free, then $t$ is always substitutable for $x$ in $\phi$".

Substitutability defined in the book like this:

> We say that $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\phi$ if
>
> 1. $\phi$ is atomic, or
> 2. $\phi :\equiv\neg\left(\alpha\right)$ and $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$, or
> 3. $\phi :\equiv \left(\alpha\vee\beta\right)$ and $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, or
> 4. $\phi :\equiv \left(\forall y\right)\left(\alpha\right)$ and either
>
>    (a) $x$ is not free in $\phi$, or
>
>    (b) $y$ does not occur in $t$ and $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$.

I think the sentence we have to show is wrong. If we look at the sentence "$\phi :\equiv \left(\forall x\right)\left(2x<x\right)$" and if $t$ is $0$, then $t$ is variable-free but it is not substitutable for $x$ in $\phi$. Problem is that both 4.a and 4.b are correct, but one of them must be wrong.

Am I missing something?

Comment: $\left(\forall x\right)\left(2x<x\right)$ isn't true. and specialising $x$ to the value $0$ doesn't produce a logically valid statement. But it's a valid substitution.

Comment: @rici that should be an answer.

Comment: Does "either 4.a or 4.b" not mean "one of them must be true, and the other must be false"?

Comment: The subst $[\forall x (2x < x)]_0^x$ is syntactically correct and the result is $\forall x (2x < x)$.

Comment: See [this similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659471/what-does-it-mean-for-a-variable-to-be-free-for-something) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Yes, but it is not substitutable from the definition 1.8.3. But the proposition we have to show is stating "every variable-free term $t$ is substitutable for any $x$ in any $\phi$"

Comment: You are misunderstanding the definition... Is $0$ substitutable for $x$ in $\forall x (2x < x)$ ? See clause 4 (a): is $x$ not free in the formula ? Yes; thus it is substitutable. In addition, see 4 (b): does $x$ not occurs in $0$ ? Yes. And is $0$ substitutable for $x$ in $(2x < x)$ ? Yes. So, all the relevant clauses are satisfied and $0$ **is** substitutable for $x$ in the formula. No contradiction at all.

Comment: See comment: "Notice that $\phi_t^x$ is defined **whether or not** $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\phi$. Usually, we will not want to do a substitution unless we check for substitutability, but we have the ability to substitute whether or not it is a good idea."

Comment: And this is the answer to the exercise also: if $t$ is a variable free term, then $x$ is **not** free in $t$ and $y$ does not occur in $t$ and (induction hypotheses) $t$ is substitutable in the sub-formula prefixed by the $\forall y$ quantifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was about the use of "$either ... or ...$", I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the whole misunderstanding comes down to the meaning of the phrase "either ... or ...".

In mathematical writing, "either $P$ or $Q$" means the same thing as "$P$ or $Q$". In particular, it is true if both $P$ and $Q$ are true.

In your example, condition 4(a) is true, so $t$ is substitutable for $x$. Also, 4(b) is true, so that's another reason why $t$ is substitutable for $x$.

Comment: YES! This is what the problem is. Just someone had to say this. Thanks a lot