# Is $y+1$ substitutable for x in the following expression?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Is $y+1$ substitutable for x in $∃y(x = 2y)$?

My answer would be no because if we substitute $x$ for $y+1$ we'd have $∃y(y+1 = 2y)$ which changes the original meaning, which would be that x is an even number.
Is this the correct way to justify it?

Comment: The answer is indeed "no" and your justification explains well the intuitive reason.  There is, however, a more rigorous answer, involving only the syntax and not the meaning of the expressions, namely to follow the formal (inductive) definition of "substitutable for ... in ...".

Comment: In a less formal sense than Andreas Blass is talking about (and surely than you are looking for, but still I want to point it out), it is perfectly fine to substitute $y + 1$ for $x$ in that expression. For $\exists y(x = 2y)$ is exactly the same expression as $\exists z(x = 2z)$ and after the substitution, you get $\exists z(y+1 = 2z)$. So substituting $y+1$ is okay. What is not okay is continuing to denote the dummy variable as $y$ when you've done so.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659471/what-does-it-mean-for-a-variable-to-be-free-for-something) for details